# How to force the usage of IPv4?

Tags: networking, ping, ipv6, ipv4

I need to check timings on my Ubuntu machine by 
`ping www.xyz.com`
but using IPv4 only. How can I check if I have both (IPv4
and IPv6) connectivity? How can I force usage of IPv4 for this particular test only?

Comment: There’s dozens of `ping` implementations. Which one are you using?

Comment: I just have to run ```ping www.xyz.com``` @DanielB

Comment: Are you using Windows?  macOS? Linux?  What version?  If Windows try `ping /4 www.xyz.com` or  `ping -4 www.xyz.com`

Comment: @lx07 nope, linux ubuntu.

Comment: `ping` (as opposed to `ping6`) will check IP4.  What are you trying to time exactly?  The time to lookup `www.xyz.com`?  Otherwise can you just do `ping 51.101.1.69` or whatever?

Comment: @lx07 I have to use ping to measure round trip time to different websites using IP4 only, not 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the ping utility uses IPv4 by default and needs to be told to use IPv6, but you should be able to specify IPv4 by using `ping -4 h.o.s.t`